# how can I insert this SQL into phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

INSERT INTO wp_gbqz_posts (post_content, post_title, post_name, post_type) VALUES ('Nilsen post content', 'Sakken post title', 'Stavanger post name', 'staff')

How can I add this to wordpress database so the url, category, post type is imported?

This is for custom post types.

Comment: Do you have access to phpMyAdmin? By the way, phpMyAdmin is an interface to MySQL.

Comment: nevermind i figured it out.  But thanks.